# Another phrase for "he is a very easy person to scare"?

Tags: phrase-requests

Can I have another phrase for the sentence/phrase;

> He is a very easy person to scare.

Please I need this because I am writing a story which I'm going to produce when I'm finished...

Comment: He is easily scared.

Comment: He's a fraidy-cat.

Comment: He's ***nervous, highly-strung***

Comment: The question needs more context really. Someone may be normally quite relaxed, but can be provoked. It depends on who is saying it too.

Comment: He is a **scaredy-cat** - https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scaredy-cat - "someone, especially a child, who is easily frightened"

Answer (score 0):

A **scaredy-cat** or **fraidy-cat** are both terms for someone easily scared. They are rather juvenile terms which might be used by children. You could also describe an easily scared person as **jumpy**, which describes a sort of jittery anxiousness prone to startling, although it may not necessarily connote fear.